# Can enum be made an output in systemverilog?

Tags: enums, verilog, system-verilog

In verilog, I can do something like this:

```
module controller (
    input rstb, clk, start,
    output reg [1:0] state, next_state
);
    parameter S_idle = 2'b00, S_1 = 2'b01, S_2 = 2'b11;

    always @ (posedge clk, negedge rstb)
    begin
        if (!rstb) state <= S_idle;
        else state <= next_state;
    end
...
endmodule
```

But in systemverilog, this will generate an error since I declared `state, next_state` twice:

```
module controller (
    input rstb, clk, start,
    output logic [1:0] state, next_state
);
    enum logic [1:0] {S_idle, S_1, S_2} state, next_state;

    always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstb)
    begin
        if (!rstb) state <= S_idle;
        else state <= next_state;
    end
...
endmodule
```

I suppose I could rename my output ports to `state_out, next_state_out` and assign them to `state, next_state`. Is there an easier way to use the enum as an output?

Comment: have you tried `module controller (
    input rstb, clk, start,
    output enum logic [1:0] {S_idle, S_1, S_2} state, next_state
);` ?

Comment: @Greg, according to the type compatibility rules in the LRM, anything you could connect to this port would be an error if you wrote it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using user defined types, you should use a `typedef` and put them in a package so they can be shared amongst the modules that use them. Otherwise you run into type incompatibility assignment errors.

```
package stuff;
  typedef enum logic [1:0] {S_idle, S_1, S_2} state_t;
endpackage


module controller import stuff::*; (
        input logic rstb, clk, start,
        output state_t state, next_state
    );
        always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstb)
        begin
            if (!rstb) state <= S_idle;
            else state <= next_state;
        end
    ...
 endmodule
```

Comment: Perhaps this line had an extra semicolon: `output stuff::state_t; state, next_state`?
I could only get this to work if I put the package in a separate file and import it. If I have the package in same file as my controller module, then I get an error saying `S_Idle` is not declared for `if (!rstb) state <= S_idle;`.

Comment: Sorry yes, that was a typo. Also forgot with `enum` you need to import the names as well as the typedef. So it's easiest to import the whole package.